# Openlayers dynamic viewport width and height assignment

Tags: javascript, css, openlayers, gis

I have an openlayers map displayed in a `<div>` tag in a html page.  i use css styles to assign the map dimensions by defining the class of the map division.

```
<div id="map" class="largemap"></div>
```

where

```
.largemap {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

i want to change the map dimensions dynamically depending on the user's window size, so i create a style element and assign this new class to the map division using javascript:

```
var mapElement = document.getElementById("map");
var sheet = document.createElement('style');
var newHeight = viewportheight-400; // previously acquired - working OK
var newWidth = viewportwidth-200; // previously acquired - working OK
var styleHTML = ".custommap {    width: "+newWidth+"px;    height: "+newHeight+"px;    border: 1px solid #ccc;}";
sheet.innerHTML = styleHTML;
document.body.appendChild(sheet);
mapElement.className = "custommap";
```

2 unintended things happen:

1. just appending the style to the document changes the class of the map division;
2. the map division still uses "old" bounds (does not center correctly on zoom);

can anyone recommend a more efficient strategy for dynamically defining the viewport in openlayers?

Comment: Might [this](http://dpporp.hzsmsk.cz/kra_mapa-povodnoveho-planu-orp/) be what you're after? Try hitting the fullscreen button and resize the window.

Comment: Can you not just set `mapdiv.style.width=newWidth` (and the same for height). Clearly, you would have to work this out from clientHeight/Width, minus any other fixed width divs you have outside the map. If it is all dynamic, then you could get the other divs dims with `$('#divid').height()` and give the map div what is left.

Comment: @JohnBarça actually, i cleaned up my HTML and css and got some clutter out of the way, i'm very close to making this approach work if i can fix the zoom issue.  but i will definitely give your suggestion a shot, as it might cut down precious processing time.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question, I thought you were talking about the map div itself, not the extent of the mapping within it. But, you got an answer anyway, and nice and simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the container size is changed you have to update the map size and recalculate bounds:

```
map.updateSize();
map.calculateBounds();
```

You can check the OL documentation http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.updateSize